# Choice of the point one on the top of the function if the number of points is odd

Tags: matlab, function, random

Given a function `f`. This function could be a sin, cos, Dirac or triangle functions. I need to find a number of points in this function.

Example: Let `f` is a triangle function and define 3 points ( random)

1. How to define randomly three points: one on the top, one on the left side and one on the right side?

Comment: How is it random if it’s always at the top?

Comment: @CrisLuengo  on the top is fixed if the # of points is odd. If the number is even, the points will be  randomly on both sides

Answer (score 0):

simple. the one on top is always fixed. you start with that point. then as long as you know the angle of the 2 sides, generate and random numbers to represent the distance from point 1 on each side.

Comment: could you give an example of how to generate it if the function is triangle?

Comment: I don't think you are giving us enough information. are the angles known? if so, what are the known angles? if nothing is known, then you can literally pick 3 random points in space and they will form a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to start with a trig function, like cos. With this in mind, we can create an example domain of x, say

```
x=-pi:0.1:pi
```

Then calculate and plot y

```
y = cos(x)
plot(x,y)
```

Now, let's find points along the domain of X. In my example I choose to pick 5 points and use `linspace` to find 5 points equally spaced along the domain. Then, I can use commands to plot the values. (Not random per se, but I don't think that was you intention.)

```
N = 5
x1 = linspace(-pi,pi,N)
hold on
plot(x1,cos(x1),"or")
```